# How do I get text on list item click?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get the text `Title-1` or `Title-2` each time I click on the corresponding `<li>`. Below is my attempt which is not working.

```html
<ul id="playlist">
<a onclick="loadSong(); get_text();"><li>Tilte-1</li></a>
<a onclick="loadSong(); get_text();"><li>Title-2</li></a>
</ul>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The better way in my opinion would be to place the data in `data-*` such as `data-title`. otherwise use `e.target.textContent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is:

```
<ul id="playlist">
    <a href="#" onclick="loadSong(); get_text(this)"><li>Tilte-1</li></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="loadSong(); get_text(this)"><li>Title-2</li></a>
</ul>

function loadSong() {
    console.log('song');
}

function get_text(e) {
    console.log(e.innerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass on the current element by passing `this` to the `get_text(this)` function:

```js
// Mocking this function.
function loadSong() {
  // Stuff
}

// Add a parameter which.
function get_text(which) {
  // Use which.innerHTML to access the content.
  console.log(which.innerHTML.trim());
}
```

```html
<ul id="playlist">
  <li><a onclick="loadSong(); get_text(this);">Tilte-1</a></li>
  <li><a onclick="loadSong(); get_text(this);">Title-2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** You should have `<li>` as the direct descendant of `<ul>` and not `<a>`. I have changed it for you.

**Note:** The other better way to do is to pass content on the `<a>` using HTML5 data attributes. Something like:

```html
<a data-title="Hello World">
```

Before you use `textContent`, please read: [kelly norton: innerText vs. textContent](https://kellegous.com/j/2013/02/27/innertext-vs-textcontent/)

Comment: I cant change them !, because if i do , them the link attributed will concerne only the <a> not the <li>

Comment: @Mchich Other than that, does this work?

Answer (score -1):

Another good approach is to do the JavaScript logic in JavaScript only.

```js
var playlist = document.getElementById("playlist");
var playlist_items = playlist.children;

for (var i = 0; i < playlist_items.length; i++) {
 playlist_items[i].onclick = function() {
       console.log(this.children[0].innerText);
   }
}
```

```html
<ul id="playlist">
<a><li>Tilte-1</li></a>
<a><li>Title-2</li></a>
</ul>
```

Comment: what if i want something like this, it will be easy, no ?

Comment: <script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.title;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
<script>

Comment: yes, it will work really easily !

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this which takes advantage of event delegation:

```js
function clickHandler(e) {
  console.log(e.target.textContent);
}

document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
```

```html
<ul id="playlist">
  <li>Tilte-1</li>
  <li>Title-2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Reason for downvote? I would like to adjust my answer if there was a valid reason for it.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<ul id="playlist">
  <li><a onclick="loadSong(); get_text(this);">Tilte-1</a></li>
  <li><a onclick="loadSong(); get_text(this);">Title-2</a></li>
</ul>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function get_text(which) {
   var x = document.title;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

something like this